# boost::bind to std::lower_bound works, but C++0x std::bind fails to compile

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, bind

I'm working on a proof of concept here for a zip iterator that conforms to STL algorithms. const correctness is incomplete and it could definitely be made much better, but it works for std::for_each, std::upper_bound and std::lower_bound. That is until I replace it with tr1::bind. At that point I fail to compile with numerous template errors. I've included the code below, but I have no idea how to trace this down. Any help is appreciated.

Container class

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class Container
{
public:
    class ZippedInfo
    {
    public:
        ZippedInfo(int& pos, Container* cont):
            m_pos(pos), 
            m_cont(cont)
            {};

        double& Bar(){ return m_cont->Bar(m_pos);}

        double& Foo(){ return m_cont->Foo(m_pos);}
    private:
        int& m_pos;
        Container* m_cont;
    };

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, ZippedInfo> 
    {
    public:
        iterator(int pos, Container* cont):
          m_Pos(pos), 
          m_Container(cont),
          m_ZippedInfo(m_Pos, cont)
          {}

          iterator():
              m_Pos(0), 
              m_Container(nullptr),
              m_ZippedInfo(m_Pos, nullptr)
          {}


        iterator(const iterator& rhs):
          m_Pos(rhs.m_Pos),
          m_Container(rhs.m_Container),
          m_ZippedInfo(m_Pos, rhs.m_Container)
        {}  

        ZippedInfo& operator*() {return m_ZippedInfo;}

        iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs)
        {
            m_Container = rhs.m_Container;
            m_Pos = rhs.m_Pos;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator& operator += (int increment)
        {
            m_Pos += increment;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator !=(const iterator& rhs)
        {
            return !(operator==(rhs));
        }

        bool operator ==(const iterator& rhs)
        {
            return m_Container == rhs.m_Container && m_Pos == rhs.m_Pos;
        }

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            m_Pos++;
            return *this;
        }

        int operator -(const iterator& rhs)
        {
            return m_Pos - rhs.m_Pos;
        }

        bool operator < (const iterator& rhs)
        {
            return m_Pos < rhs.m_Pos;
        }
    private:
        int m_Pos;
        ZippedInfo m_ZippedInfo;
        Container* m_Container;
    };

    Container() {}
    Container(const std::vector<double> &bar, const std::vector<double>& foo):
        m_bar(bar),
        m_foo(foo)
    {   }


    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(0, this);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(m_foo.size(), this);
    }

    double& Foo(int index){return m_foo[index];}
    double& Bar(int index){return m_bar[index];}
private:
    std::vector<double> m_foo;
    std::vector<double> m_bar;
};
```

Main program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <boost\bind.hpp>
#include "test_iter.h"

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<double> foo;
    foo.push_back(1);
    foo.push_back(2);
    foo.push_back(3);
    foo.push_back(4);
    foo.push_back(5);

    vector<double>bar;
    bar.push_back(1);
    bar.push_back(3);
    bar.push_back(5);
    bar.push_back(7);
    bar.push_back(9);

    Container c(bar, foo);

    double searchnum = 3;


    /*Container::iterator cf_iter3 = std::lower_bound(c.begin(), 
                                        c.end(), 
                                        searchnum,
                                        std::tr1::bind(&Container::ZippedInfo::Bar, std::tr1::placeholders::_1) < searchnum );*/

    Container::iterator cf_iter2 = std::lower_bound(c.begin(), 
                                        c.end(), 
                                        searchnum,
                                        boost::bind(&Container::ZippedInfo::Bar, _1) < searchnum );

    cout << (*cf_iter2).Bar() << endl;
```

The boost version works, the tr1 version gives the following errors

```
error C2065: 'cf_iter' : undeclared identifier
error C2228: left of '.Bar' must have class/struct/union
error C2676: binary '<' : 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
error C2780: '_FwdIt std::lower_bound(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::tr1::operator <(const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> &,const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
error C2784: 'bool std::tr1::operator <(const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> &,const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> &' from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
```

Comment: Just so you know, Boost already has a zip iterator that conforms to STL algorithms -- [Boost.Iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html)' [`boost::zip_iterator<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

Comment: thanks ildjarn, I was aware of that, but the tuple it returned was particularly unuser friendly for the object I have

Comment: How are tuples ever unfriendly? They're the friendliest of the new types I've met, and an altogether exemplary type at large :-)

Comment: @kerrek SB - the zip iterator I'm writing has 8 arrays, all of which make sense to be grouped together, and I don't want people to have to keep going back to the documentation when I can instead give a descriptive name. I do use tuples generally, but I want to expose descriptive names in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talking about C++0x here, make the suitable adaptations for TR1 if you please.

`std::bind` differs from `boost::bind` in that it does not provide convenience overloads for operators. Using [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators), we can build the standard replacement:

```
Container::iterator cf_iter3 = std::lower_bound(c.begin(), c.end(), searchnum,
   std::bind(std::less<double>(),
             std::bind(&Container::ZippedInfo::Bar, std::placeholders::_1),
             searchnum)
                                               );
```